# In ASP.NET MVC, execution time of @Html.Partial("AuthorPartial") vs Html.RenderPartial("AuthorPartial")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

In ASP.NET MVC, which method is better in terms of execution time?

```
1)    @Html.Partial("AuthorPartial") 

2)    Html.RenderPartial("AuthorPartial")
```

Comment: Can you please share the link of the question? @stephen Muecke

Comment: Its at the top of your question :)

Comment: I have read it no comparison of execution time?

Comment: Point 6 of the top rated answer :) And if you want actual times, then do it yourself!

Comment: This method is faster than Partial method since its result is directly written to the response stream which makes it fast.

Got it thanks :)